# App runs if I activate breakpoints, fails otherwise

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I have an app that uses sockets to send login information to a server and receives a response in form of a contact list. This is the main method for processing responses from server:

```
-(void) stream:(NSStream*)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

switch(streamEvent) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        if(theStream == inputStream) {
            uint8_t buffer[8196];
            int len;
            while([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if(len>0) {
                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    if(output != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);

                        id jsonOutput = [self createJsonFromString:output];
                        if([[jsonOutput objectForKey:@"msg_type"] isEqualToString:@"LoginResponse"])
                        {
                            [self sendMessage:[self createAddressBookRequestJsonData]];

                        } else if ([[jsonOutput objectForKey:@"msg_type"] isEqualToString:@"GetAddressBookResponse"])
                        {
                            id contactList = [jsonOutput objectForKey:@"contact_list"];
                            for(id contactListItem in contactList)
                            {
                                XYZAddressBookEntry *newEntry = [[XYZAddressBookEntry alloc] init];
                                newEntry.firstName =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
                                newEntry.lastName =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"LastName"];
                                newEntry.displayName =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"DisplayName"];
                                newEntry.softphoneNumber =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"SoftphoneNumber"];
                                newEntry.homeNumber =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"HomeNumber"];
                                newEntry.mobileNumber =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"MobileNumber"];
                                newEntry.businessNumber =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"BusinessNumber"];
                                newEntry.name =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"Name"];
                                newEntry.phoneAddress =  [contactListItem objectForKey:@"PhoneAddress"];
                                [self.entryList addObject:newEntry];
                            }
                           [self.tableView reloadData];
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        break;

    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        break;

    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event:");
}    }
```

I always get a correct output in my log, so everything goes smooth, but if I don't set a breakpoint right after NSLog(@"server said: %@", output), it will not enter the if else code block. What am I missing?

By the way, I'm a newbie to this, started using objective-c just 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Let's add {} in those cases, sometimes it would mess up

Comment: Maybe put logs for every event, to make sure they're all happening as you expect. PS I HIGHLY recommend using [this](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) library to do your socket comms.

Comment: Yes CocoaAsyncSocket will make your life easier.

Comment: You can also use AFNetworking - http://afnetworking.com.  Code like this - ` uint8_t buffer[8196];` is just asking for a crash

Comment: @PokeyMcPokerson Thanks for the link. This library is so much easier to work with.